# How to improve Lighthouse score Time to interactive in Sapper

Tags: javascript, performance, svelte, lighthouse, sapper

we currently have an abysymal low performance score on our website being built with *sapper* and *svelte*. Which is kind of strange, as it's selling point is that it is blazingly fast. So my question is whether I am doing something horribly wrong. The problem seems to the *Time to Interactive*. It is really slow with over 9 seconds. Is there a way to boost this? The basic structure of my *_layout.svelte* looks like this:

```
<main class="hyphenate">
  <Header />
  <div class="content-main">
    <slot />

    {#if showModal}
      <ConsentModal
        close={() => (showModal = false)} />
    {/if}
  </div>
  <Footer />
  <div class="sponsoring">
    <div class="sponsoring-images">
      <a target="_blank"  class="logo">
        <Image width={150} alt="Cispa Logo" />
      </a>
      <a target="_blank"  class="logo">
          <Image />
      </a>
      <p>partner text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Are there some obvious improvements I don't see? Like moving the Header and the Footer to every single page instead of using the layout? Also does it make sense to move all tracking software which is initialized in the *html* template to some later point? The great problem seems to be images and fonts. Checking out the screenshots, I can see that the *html* is almost instantly there, but the images - which are lazy loaded - take a short time as well as an icon in the header. Is there a way to speed this up? Here is a picture of the time it takes to be fully interactive:

[image: Lighthouse Performance]

As you can see, there is a huge time where the app is idle. Can this be somehow tweaked? I am very thankful for any pointer into the right direction.

Comment: Consider raising an issue for this.  I see similar results.  There are some similar issues open but nothing specifically about time to interactive.  This one could be related: https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/934

Comment: Try running lighthouse in incognito mode.  In my case, my extensions were negatively affecting the results.  The time to interactive score went from 8.3s to 2.6s.

Comment: I used it on a new installation of chrome, as firefox is my default browser. So that should not be an issue. Also I use the export command to get the assets, so in that case there shouldn't be a service worker, or?

Comment: I think it could still be an issue.  By default, the service worker aggressively caches all files created by the bundler and all the files in the static directory.  This includes any files in the static directory that are never used.  I found this video by someone who had a related issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OW8pt756dU

Comment: Ok, but how can I remove the service worker? Or tell him to not cache?

Comment: I just deleted the service worker and it reduced the Time to Interactive by 2s! But there should be a better method than to completely remove it.

Comment: @digby280 Lighthouse doesn't have anything to do with your browser or machine. It sends HTTP GET to your website from a simulated low performance, slow 3G phone from their servers, also from a desktop, that's why you see the results both for mobile and desktop. It does take caching into consideration for calculating the final score, but its weightage is very low and makes absolutely no difference to the TTI. OP, as the code shared by you doesn't tell the end to end page load story, would you mind telling your website name. I'm quite hopeful of helping you with this :)

Comment: @VivekSingh I think you've missed the point.  The sapper service worker makes a lot of additional HTTP GET requests before the page is loaded.  By default, it gets all static assets and prevents the page from loading.  This behaviour is easily observable.  Changing or removing the service worker resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on from our discussion in the comments above.

This PR definitely helps: https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/pull/1052
It's a little old now so I'm not sure when it will get merged.

I'd recommend taking a look at the files that get cached when the service worker is installed.  You may find they are not appropriate for your app.  If you are using the standard template you can find the list of files here: src/node_modules/@sapper/service-worker.js.  Notice despite the common filename this is not the same as src/service-worker.js.

To be honest, your approach of just removing the service worker might be right for you.  At the moment those precached assets don't get served by the service worker anyway due to this issue: https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/1210.  As such, one alternative would be to just remove the precaching logic.  That way you'd get all the benefits of the service worker without the issues you've been seeing.  The service worker would just use a network or cache strategy, so requests will get lazily cached and used if the user goes offline.

Comment: I only have a *sapper* folder instead of an *@sapper* folder and it does not contain a *service-worker.js* file. Is the precahing logic in this function ```self.addEventListener("fetch"``` in *service-worker.js* within the *src* folder?

Comment: The precaching logic is this line in the "install" event handler: `.then(cache => cache.addAll(to_cache))`.

Comment: The src/node_modules/@sapper directory is created as part of the build.  It's used for intermediate build artefacts.  It is configured here: https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/blob/25eb60f60370b01d4fa767734c54ef9f8dc0e3cd/src/api/build.ts#L30.  If you run "npm run build" it should appear unless your build is overriding the default.

Comment: Hm, I used the template, so that should not happen.